# Network sharing not working on windows, with local IP. But can access by localhost

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I have two windows 10 machine, and  the same configuration in:
 Installed windows feature ,
 firewall,
 advanced sharing settings,
 running services.

One ACER machine has no problem, can be access by MAC OS too.
But another MSI computer can only see the sharing folders by //127.0.0.1 and //localhost.
and can not access by localhost,  My DHCP give it IP as //192.168.1.118

Therefor no other computer can access the  MSI computer.

Here are  services  I am running, regarding to this issue.
· DNS Client
· Function Discovery Provider Host
· Function Discovery Resource Publication
· Peer Networking Grouping
· HomeGroup Provider
· HomeGroup Listener
· SSDP Discovery
· UPnP Device Host

SMB service seems not bind to my IP  .

Here messages from ACER computer when trying to access MSI SMB

> file and print sharing resource (MSI) is online but isn't responding to 
>       connection attempts.
>      The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 445, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings,
>       or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems with the firewall on your computer.

Here are logs from  `netsh interface ip show address`  on MSI computer

> Configuration for interface "local connection* 2"
>       DHCP enabled:                         Yes
>       InterfaceMetric:                      25
>
> Configuration for interface "WLAN"
>       DHCP enabled:                         Yes
>       IP Address:                           192.168.1.118
>       Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.1.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
>       Default Gateway:                      192.168.1.1
>       Gateway Metric:                       0
>       InterfaceMetric:                      55
>
> Configuration for interface "localconnection* 3"
>       DHCP enabled:                         No
>       IP Address:                           192.168.137.1
>       Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.137.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
>       InterfaceMetric:                      55
>
> Configuration for interface "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"
>       DHCP enabled:                         No
>       IP Address:                           127.0.0.1
>       Subnet Prefix:                        127.0.0.0/8 (mask 255.0.0.0)
>       InterfaceMetric:                      75

Comment: As the problem is on the MSI computer why are you giving us all that detail about the ACER computer ? This all looks like if the MSI thinks it is on a "public" network and therefore blocks SMB.

Comment: Your are right,  ACER log not that helpful,  it just windows diagnostics logs,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many tries,   The issue is from Visual Studio.
Before Install VS,  I enabled IIS.   VS also install IIS express.
Not 100% sure that cause the issue, but after unsintall VS ,  SMB is working again, and FTP. HTTP server is also working again with local IP.

Also Uninstall several VS installed packages:

- IIS 10.0 express
- MS SQL server 2012 Native Client
- Microsoft Web deploy 3.6
- Microsoft MPI
- MIcrosoft Identity extensions
- MIcrosoft AS OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016
- Microsoft Azure Authoring tools
- Microsoft Azure Compute emulate
- Microsoft Azure Libraries for .Net
- Microsoft Azure Mobile APP SDK
- Microsoft Azure Power Shell
- Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator

Answer (score 1):

Tip: ipconfig /all dumps too much data; In the future consider:

```
netsh interface ip show address
```

That being said: is your MSI computer on a private network with discovery and file sharing enabled? If so have you checked your firewall settings? The easiest way to test if it's a firewall problem: temporarily disable the firewall (this assumes you are on a home network and trust the other devices on the network) and then try to connect. If the connection goes through then we know it was the firewall causing the problem. You will then want to re-enable the firewall and then start checking your inbound rules.

Comment: I have tried firewall disabled and discovery and file sharing enabled. but that is not the reason.
The symptom is SMB service not running  on local port.   
//192.168.1.118 should works first   , then test  access from another computer.